# How move only a part of an image whith hover

Tags: css, hover, css-sprites

I have one image that contains severals words,
when a word like "good" or never is hover, i want to move it.

For one image i know how to do that:

```
#imgHover:hover { margin-top: -5px; }
<img id="imgHover" src="http://www.phrases.org.uk/images/most-common-words-in-english-proverbs-1.gif"/>
```

But i want to move only certain words, like "good".

Is it possible in CSS?

Thanks!
...

Comment: you may be able to clip the image to the word, but for multiple words you would need to clip multiple images... defeating the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

To be simple... not if the words are in the same image. Make separate images for each word.

Comment: If i separate the image in severals images,
the issue is in my HTML page, there are some blank lines between images :s.

Comment: What black lines? Got a print? And some code? With that I might help you.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. You can't use CSS to move parts of an image apart from each other.

You're probably best off using separate images, or setting the text in HTML. With HTML text, you can do something like this, e.g. like so:

```
<span class="word">Hi this is <span class="move">good</span></span>
```

and then

```
span.word span.move:hover { position: relative; top: -15px }
```

Comment: When i want to display separating images I have one white blank between images :(

Comment: @superscral there's no reason for that to happen. Do you have a background colour set?

Comment: No bakground color set
I have this:

`<img src="img/part1.png" style="display: block" border="0"/>

<table id="Tableau_02" width="520" height="50" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr> 
                <td>
                        <img src="img/part21.png"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                        <img id="imgHover" src="img/part22.png"/>
                </td> 
                <td>
                        <img src="img/part23.png"/>
                </td>
        </tr>
</table>`

and between part1 and part_21 i have a white line

Comment: @super that might come from the table's background. You should need that table at all though?

Comment: If I must seperates the images and then display all images, yes.

Or which a div and css whith maximum with maybe ...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the image as a background of an element and reposition the background:

```
#img
{
  background:url("img.png") no-repeat 0 0;
  width:123px;
  height:10px;
}

#img:hover
{
  background-position:0 -5px;
}
```

Your HTML should look like:

```
<div id="img"></div>
```

Hovering over the div will move the background up 5 pixels. Note that you need to take dimensions into account.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS sprites would probably solve your problem: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/